# wild card with bind9

Tags: wildcard, wildcard-subdomain, bind9

I am trying to set up a special DNSBL service using bind9.
I found the wild card entries in zone files behaving rather strangely.

The idea is to resolve all DNS queries to

- <unless.blocked.dnsbl.local> => 127.0.0.100
- any.blacklisted.dnsbl.local => 127.0.0.250

> I specified a zone file in /etc/bind/named.local like this:

```
zone "dnsbl.local." {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.in.dnsbl.local";
        allow-transfer { any; };
        allow-query { any; };
};
```

> And in the zone file /etc/bind/db.in.dnsbl.local:

```
; BIND data file for TLD ".dnsbl.local"
;
$TTL    604800
$ORIGIN dnsbl.local.

@       IN      SOA     ns.dnsbl.local. root.dnsbl.local. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         14400 )       ; Negative Cache TTL

@   IN  NS  ns
@   IN  A   127.0.0.1
@   IN  AAAA    ::1

ns  IN  A   127.0.0.1

allowed   IN    A       127.0.0.100
blocked   IN    A       127.0.0.250
dns01     IN    CNAME   blocked
apache01  IN    CNAME   blocked
mysql01   IN    CNAME   blocked
postfix01 IN    CNAME   blocked
dovecot01 IN    CNAME   blocked
rediff.com      IN      CNAME   blocked
flipkart.com    IN      CNAME   blocked
*.dnsbl.local.    IN    CNAME       allowed
```

> Now when I check, here's what I get as expected:
> $ dig flipkart.com.dnsbl.local

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.18-Ubuntu <<>> flipkart.com.dnsbl.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 25300
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 7dce372de146f0d9beb6d65665f983dbc6881a3ff139bea8 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;flipkart.com.dnsbl.local.      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
flipkart.com.dnsbl.local. 604800 IN     CNAME   blocked.dnsbl.local.
blocked.dnsbl.local.    604800  IN      A       127.0.0.250

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dnsbl.local.            604800  IN      NS      ns.dnsbl.local.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.dnsbl.local.         604800  IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 19 17:53:55 IST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 152
```

> However for 
> $ dig google.com.dnsbl.local

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.18-Ubuntu <<>> google.com.dnsbl.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 27078
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 972c294bcda6d369824cd2a865f984433b37ef4e9e9453a7 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.dnsbl.local.                IN      A
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dnsbl.local.            14400   IN      SOA     ns.dnsbl.local. root.dnsbl.local. 2 604800 86400 2419200 14400
;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 19 17:55:39 IST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 123
```

***I expected it to resolve to CNAME => allowed.com.dnsbl.com => 127.0.0.100, but it doesn't!***

> However strangely for:
> google.com.x.dnsbl.local it resolves to CNAME allowed.dnsbl.local => 127.0.0.100

> $ dig google.com.x.dnsbl.local

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.18-Ubuntu <<>> google.com.x.dnsbl.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50850
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 18987b3a55a0abfcc4edb01565f984d9758cba76c1c5a2c0 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.x.dnsbl.local.      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.x.dnsbl.local. 604800 IN     CNAME   allowed.dnsbl.local.
allowed.dnsbl.local.    604800  IN      A       127.0.0.100

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dnsbl.local.            604800  IN      NS      ns.dnsbl.local.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.dnsbl.local.         604800  IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 19 17:58:09 IST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 152
```

> And also for 
> $ dig google.net.dnsbl.local

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.18-Ubuntu <<>> google.net.dnsbl.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15841
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: e7d23bffd1f25b171719188365f98f5cbbd45a92e4d57803 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.net.dnsbl.local.                IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.net.dnsbl.local. 604800  IN      CNAME   allowed.dnsbl.local.
allowed.dnsbl.local.    604800  IN      A       127.0.0.100

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dnsbl.local.            604800  IN      NS      ns.dnsbl.local.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.dnsbl.local.         604800  IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 19 18:43:00 IST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 150
```

Wish to understand:

1. Why google.com.x.dnsbl.local resolves to allowed.dnsbl.local =>
   127.0.0.100
2. But google.com.dnsbl.local results in NXDOMAIN
3. What should I do to make this work.

I am sure there's some hack out there who can help me figure this.

Thanks in advance.